# sys_call_table information not found

Tags: debugging, linux-kernel, system-calls

I am writing a kernel module which can read the sys_call_table address using kallsyms_lookup_name() function defined at kallsyms.h in linux kernel. I have seen sample codes which use this methods to get the sys_call_table address but in my code as attached I am getting 0 returned from it. I have enabled CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y in linux configuration to include debug informations.

`void set_sct_addr(void) {  sct_address = (void*)kallsyms_lookup_name("sys_call_table");    printk(KERN_ALERT "The base address of the table is %lx\n",sct_address); }`

The sys_call_table address is also not seen in the /proc/kallsyms file too. I tried to grep but had no luck in that. I would like to know what I am missing while writing this module in linux.

Thanks.

The sys_call_table address is to be taken from the function defined in kallsyms.h

Comment: Which linux version?

Comment: Which architecture?

Comment: I am working with RISCV Arch @Sagar

Comment: It is linux kernel 5.5-rc1 on RISCV Arch @steve

Comment: Right now I am using the value of the sys_call_table from the System.map file (hard-coded in driver) but using that when I try to check umask call it works while it doesnt work for other commands like "id" or other commands. "umask 22" works for me fine. [https://github.com/PinkP4nther/Sutekh/blob/master/sutekh.c ] (writing based on this).